# Google Analytics response to Pandas Dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-analytics

Still a newbie to Python so please be gentle.

I'm trying to parse a Google Analytics Reporting API V4 response to a Pandas dataframe in Python, specifically using Repl if that makes any difference. I've tried a few commonly accepted answers from SO but none seem to be working. The code 'successfully' (no error msgs) executes but even basic print('Done') commands at the end of the script aren't showing up in the terminal.

Can anyone see what might be wrong with my code?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize

response = {'reports':[{'columnHeader':{'dimensions':['ga:date','ga:sourceMedium','ga:landingPagePath','ga:deviceCategory','ga:browser'],'metricHeader':{'metricHeaderEntries':[{'name':'ga:sessions','type':'INTEGER'}]}},'data':{'rows':[{'dimensions':['20201126','(direct) / (none)','/test/page.html','desktop','Chrome'],'metrics':[{'values':['1']}]}],'totals':[{'values':['1000']}],'rowCount':100,'minimums':[{'values':['1']}],'maximums':[{'values':['10']}],'isDataGolden':True},'nextPageToken':'1'}]}

def parse_data(response):

  reports = response['reports'][0]
  columnHeader = reports['columnHeader']['dimensions']
  metricHeader = reports['columnHeader']['metricHeader']['metricHeaderEntries']

  columns = columnHeader
  for metric in metricHeader:
    columns.append(metric['name'])

  data = pd.json_normalize(reports['data']['rows'])
  data_dimensions = pd.DataFrame(data['dimensions'].tolist())
  data_metrics = pd.DataFrame(data['metrics'].tolist())
  data_metrics = data_metrics.applymap(lambda x: x['values'])
  data_metrics = pd.DataFrame(data_metrics[0].tolist())
  result = pd.concat([data_dimensions, data_metrics], axis=1, ignore_index=True)

  return result
  print(result)
  result.to_csv('result.csv')
  print('Done')
```

Answer (score 5):

It's because in a given function, any code that occurs after the `return` statement is not executed. Once `return` is reached, the function is done. If you put your `print` call and `to_csv` method before the `return` statement, they should run.

Try reorganizing your code as such:

```
def parse_data(response):

  reports = response['reports'][0]
  columnHeader = reports['columnHeader']['dimensions']
  metricHeader = reports['columnHeader']['metricHeader']['metricHeaderEntries']

  columns = columnHeader
  for metric in metricHeader:
    columns.append(metric['name'])

  data = pd.json_normalize(reports['data']['rows'])
  data_dimensions = pd.DataFrame(data['dimensions'].tolist())
  data_metrics = pd.DataFrame(data['metrics'].tolist())
  data_metrics = data_metrics.applymap(lambda x: x['values'])
  data_metrics = pd.DataFrame(data_metrics[0].tolist())
  result = pd.concat([data_dimensions, data_metrics], axis=1, ignore_index=True)

  print(result)
  result.to_csv('result.csv')
  print('Done')
  return result
```

Comment: Good call out! Sadly that didn't seem to solve the issue. Same result. :(

Comment: This code works if you specify `pd.json_normalize` rather than just `json_normalize`

Answer (score 2):

I would just modify the above function, in order to add colum names as well:

```
def parse_data(response):
reports = response['reports'][0]
columnHeader = reports['columnHeader']['dimensions']
metricHeader = reports['columnHeader']['metricHeader']['metricHeaderEntries']
#Get dimenssion names
dim_names = [columnHeader[n].split(":")[1] for n in range (len(columnHeader))]
#Get metric names
metric_names = [metricHeader[n]['name'].split(":")[1] for n in range (len(metricHeader))]
column_names = dim_names+metric_names


columns = columnHeader
for metric in metricHeader:
    columns.append(metric['name'])

data = pd.json_normalize(reports['data']['rows'])
data_dimensions = pd.DataFrame(data['dimensions'].tolist())
data_metrics = pd.DataFrame(data['metrics'].tolist())
data_metrics = data_metrics.applymap(lambda x: x['values'])
data_metrics = pd.DataFrame(data_metrics[0].tolist())
result = pd.concat([data_dimensions, data_metrics], axis=1, ignore_index=True)

# Assign columns names to DF
result.columns = column_names
print(result)
result.to_csv('result.csv')
print('Done')
return result
```